# API coingecko data - doNotDelete

Tags: api, google-sheets, cryptography, coingecko

I use Coingecko's importJSON code to load data into a Google Sheet. The last parameter of the url (see below) is called *'doNotDelete!$A$!'*. If I run the importJSON function in my sheet a numeric value in cell A1 of the tab doNotDelete shows up. What does this number mean? Is it the number of seconds that past since last execution? There is no explanation about it in the Coingecko's article about their API ImportJSON function for Google Sheets.

> =ImportJSON("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=2&sparkline=false","/name,/current_price,/market_cap,/price_change,/total_volume,/high_24h,/low_24h","noTruncate,noHeaders",**doNotDelete!$A$1**)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When the value of this cell changes ImportJSON gets updated values from the API. It doesn't have any meaningful value, your autorefresh script should change that to a random value whenever it is run.
It's not coingecko's script, it is from [here](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) and it is currently unmaintained, so if google changes the behavior of any of the used functions it can stop working.